# Wordpress <?php the_post_thumbnail( 'full' ); ?> without the img-tag

Tags: php, wordpress

I have noticed that using the post_thumbnail() function in Wordpress inserts the image including the img-tag. Is there a way to have it insert ONLY the src of that image?

Sofar i have tried this

```
$image = get_the_post_thumbnail( $post->ID, 'thumbnail' ); echo $image;
```

but it just exports the same.
Any ideas? thanks in advance for your help :)

Comment: and you can use wordpress.stackexchange.com for further questions

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Found answer. Thanks anyway.

```
<?php
//Get the Thumbnail URL
$src = wp_get_attachment_image_src( get_post_thumbnail_id($post->ID), array(320,240), false, '' );
echo $src[0];
?>
```

Comment: And before you ask: Will accept this answer in 2 days when I am allowed to accept it! :)

Comment: Please note that this will generate extra database queries, which could be a problem if you use it in a loop when fetching multiple posts.

Comment: Digging deeper into this, it seems like get_the_post_thumbnail() also generates additional queries, probably because post thumbnails make use of the attachment system. I guess this is unavoidable if we want to use WP's built-in featured image functionality.

Answer (score 0):

Post Thumbnail Linking to large Image Size
This example links to the “large” Post Thumbnail image size and must be used within The Loop.

```
if ( has_post_thumbnail() ) {
$large_image_url = wp_get_attachment_image_src( get_post_thumbnail_id( $post->ID ), 'large' );
if ( ! empty( $large_image_url[0] ) ) {
    echo '<a href="' . esc_url( $large_image_url[0] ) . '" title="' . the_title_attribute( array( 'echo' => 0 ) ) . '">';
    echo get_the_post_thumbnail( $post->ID, 'thumbnail' ); 
    echo '</a>';
}}
```

Source : https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/get_the_post_thumbnail/